# How to find out which ANSI C standard my gcc works with by default?

Tags: c, gcc

I read [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) it is C90 with extensions. How can I know for sure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-std=`  flag to specify a language dialect: `c89`, `c99`, `c++98`, etc. Note that `c90` is equivalent to `c89`.

As a shorthand `-ansi` causes `-std=c89` in C mode and `-std=c++98` in C++ mode.

Use `-pedantic` to enable all diagnostics that the standards require.

The defaults are `gnu89` for C and `gnu++98` for C++. Consult the manual for detailed descriptions of the various dialects.

Comment: Which of these is the default? Is there a option in gcc which tells me see the default version?

Comment: @Bruce: Added! Note that the C++ default may change eventually :-)

Comment: What do you mean by *C mode* and *C++ mode*? Recently I read that [GCC 4.8 Aims To Switch To C++ Mode By Default](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA4MzI). What does it mean?

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you know, please answer my question posed in my previous comment. I want to know it, on the fly, without creating a topic on it. :D

Comment: @Nawaz: That's something completely different - that refers to the way GCC itself is built. There's been an option to build it as C++ for a long time, but it's always been "experimental".

Comment: @KerrekSB: What does *"build it as C++"* mean in this context? By "build", I understand compiling, resolving and creating machine code (DLL/EXE/LIB/etc) out of the code, but then *"build it as C++"* doesn't make sense to me, hence the confusion. Do you mean *"program/code it in C++"*?

Comment: @Nawaz: It means that the compiler itself will be compiled with g++, not with gcc. I assume that means that the compiler's source code is treated as C++. Does that make sense?

Comment: This answer is now outdated. Release 5.0 changed the default to `-std=c11`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38193215/827263).

Answer (score 11):

Try below command and search for `std`

```
gcc -v --help | less
```

It will show you all the available options for your gcc.

Comment: But not which option is used by default.

Comment: On a Unix-like system, this will extract just the relevant bits from gcc: `gcc -v --help 2> /dev/null | grep 'Conform.*C standard'`

Answer (score 7):

Read the manpage.  On my computer (OSX 10.7, gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)):

> -std=
>           Determine the language standard. This option is currently only supported
>           when compiling C or C++.
>
> A value for this option must be provided; possible values are
>
> ....
>
> gnu89
>                   Default, ISO C90 plus GNU extensions (including some C99 features).
>
> ....
>
> gnu++98
>                   The same as -std=c++98 plus GNU extensions. This is the default for C++ code.

Comment: Works for GCC for me but not for Clang.

Comment: Ummm `man gcc` says that there isn't a man page for gcc. Wat?

Comment: I'd prefer to get that information from the compiler itself in case we're working with multiple toolchains and MANPATH isn't set for the compiler in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check one of the [predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros), for example whether your GCC asks for ANSI C (**STRICT__ANSI**) by default (i.e. without any cli arguments).

Comment: No version of gcc is fully conforming to any ANSI/ISO standard by default.

Answer (score 0):

No version of gcc fully conforms to any ANSI or ISO C standard by default.  The default is always equivalent to `-std=gnuNN`, supporting the given standard with GNU-specific extensions.  Prior to version 5 (and going back a number of years), the default was `-std=gnu90`.  Starting with version 5, the default is `-std=gnu11`.

There have been three ISO C standards: C90, C99, and C11.  (C95 was a minor amendment to C90.)  The first ANSI C standard was published in 1989, and is known as C89; it describes the same language as the ISO C90 standard.

To find out the default language version for the gcc you have running, type

```
 info gcc
```

search for the phrase "The default".

This assumes that you have the gcc documentation installed, that the documentation shown by `info gcc` matches the version of gcc you're running, and that the wording is similar enough that searching for "The default" will find the correct information.  None of these is guaranteed. Older gcc manuals may be organized differently.

More reliably, run

```
gcc --version
```

to see what version you're running, then visit the [GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) page and read the documentation for the version you're running.

More simply, if you have a version before 5.0, the default is `-std=gnu89`; otherwise the default is `-std=gnu11`. (That may change in a future release, but only some time after a new ISO C standard is published and the gcc maintainers have had time to implement it and decide to make it the default.  Don't hold your breath.)

Or you can avoid the question altogether by specifying the version you want using the `-std=...` command-line option.