# Print the latest C++ standard that gcc supports

Tags: c++, gcc

The GCC-family compilers accept an argument to specify the language standard that the compiler can use.

For example, `gcc` has `--std=gnu++20` (or `--std=gnu++2a`) and `gcc` has `--std=gnu18`.

What I expect is a way (`bash` script preferred) to print the latest standard supported by my local `gcc`. So far I cannot even find a way to print all the standards supported by my local `gcc`.

Note: not to be confused with the following since I am asking for the LATEST std not DEFAULT std:
[How to find out which ANSI C standard my gcc works with by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458340/how-to-find-out-which-ansi-c-standard-my-gcc-works-with-by-default)

Comment: Your compiler version might for example, support C++20. But not all features. What are you trying to achieve? Take a loot at [C++ compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) on cppreference.

Comment: @TonyTannous I am writing a CMake script that will, every time when I compile, use the latest C++ standard supported by the local gcc. Please note that sometimes the latest standard supported on local gcc can be newer / older than that of CMake, so please do not use CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD command.

Comment: StenSoft's answer is how you'd do it, but I'd say don't bother. There is no reason to use the latest future standard without knowing the code will actually compile or work correctly with that standard.

Comment: `gcc -v --help` also contains a list of all supported values for `-std=`.

Comment: @ssbssa That is what I am looking for. I tried `gcc --help` without `-v` before but it printed nothing. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much thanks to [@ssbssa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983398/ssbssa). Here's a draft version of the bash script that works as intended

(on `gcc 10` for C++ standards):

```sh
$ gcc -v --help 2>/dev/null | egrep "gnu\+\+[^I]+ISO [^1]"
  -std=gnu++11                Conform to the ISO 2011 C++ standard with GNU extensions.
  -std=gnu++14                Conform to the ISO 2014 C++ standard with GNU extensions.
  -std=gnu++17                Conform to the ISO 2017 C++ standard with GNU extensions.
  -std=gnu++20                Conform to the ISO 2020 C++ draft standard with GNU extensions (experimental and incomplete support).  Same as -std=gnu++2a.
  -std=gnu++2a                Conform to the ISO 2020 C++ draft standard with GNU extensions (experimental and incomplete support).
```

Edit: the final version of the script is:

```
$ gcc -v --help 2>/dev/null | egrep  "gnu\+\+[^I]+ISO [^1]" | egrep -o "\-[^ ]+" | tail -n 1
-std=gnu++2a
```

Comment: That's probably about the best you can do, but it can break if a future gcc changes the syntax of its help message. Note that it doesn't work for clang; `clang --help` says "-std=<value>            Language standard to compile for".

Comment: `gnu++XX` is not C++ standard, it's just C++XX plus GNU extensions. To get the real C++ standard you need to grep for `-std=c++`

Answer (score 1):

You can detect this by running it with an empty input file and different `-std` arguments and checking if it compiles. That's how CMake does it.

Comment: What if a new standard was proposed? Say, if `C++ 30` is out someday, there is no way for me to "know" this ahead of time unless I loop the last two-digit number from top-down and see if it compiles.

Comment: @jerryc05 Yeah, that's the idea. There's no guarantees though. You're doing a heuristic here that assumes a specific format for the `-std` argument.