# How to tell what versions of C++ are availavbe for g++ and clang

Tags: c++, g++

Simple enough.
I can chose the version of g++ or clang by passing it the --std option.
How can I get g++ or clang to spew out which versions are avilable?

Comment: For GCC/G++ I just found this https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html Though some features from C++20 are still not finished yet, and I hadn't even realised C++ 23 was even a thing yet.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand here's clang https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html Basically, Both fully support C++ 98-17 and C++ 20 is not fully finished yet. By the way, I found this with two simple google searches, and I think it would have saved you a lot of time if you had done the same.

Comment: You will also find useful information here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: None of this is in anyway responsive. The question is which options does -std support on _my_ compiler, aka the compiler installed on my computer. Does it accept as an option    -std=C++2a? or -std=C++20 or -std=C++1z. I want the list of vaild options to -std.

Comment: @Thad_The_Man did you look further into the link? There is a subheading for each standard and in that subheading, it tells which `-std=` argument is required to use that standard. I'm assuming you have the newest version of g++/clang, in which case everything in the links should work.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way around testing if the compiler option is supported like described here [Print the latest C++ standard that gcc supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236475)

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you care about versions of GCC, or versions of C++? Some obscure features of standard C++ are not well supported in GCC.

Comment: This is some [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Explain what happens to you if your GCC compiler does not accept your C++ code as you believe it should.

Answer (score 7):

For clang:

```
$ touch 1.c 1.cpp;clang -std=x 1.c 1.cpp
error: invalid value 'x' in '-std=x'
note: use 'c89', 'c90', or 'iso9899:1990' for 'ISO C 1990' standard
note: use 'iso9899:199409' for 'ISO C 1990 with amendment 1' standard
note: use 'gnu89' or 'gnu90' for 'ISO C 1990 with GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c99' or 'iso9899:1999' for 'ISO C 1999' standard
note: use 'gnu99' for 'ISO C 1999 with GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c11' or 'iso9899:2011' for 'ISO C 2011' standard
note: use 'gnu11' for 'ISO C 2011 with GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c17', 'iso9899:2017', 'c18', or 'iso9899:2018' for 'ISO C 2017' standard
note: use 'gnu17' or 'gnu18' for 'ISO C 2017 with GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c2x' for 'Working Draft for ISO C2x' standard
note: use 'gnu2x' for 'Working Draft for ISO C2x with GNU extensions' standard
error: invalid value 'x' in '-std=x'
note: use 'c++98' or 'c++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++98' or 'gnu++03' for 'ISO C++ 1998 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++11' for 'ISO C++ 2011 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++14' for 'ISO C++ 2014 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments' standard
note: use 'gnu++17' for 'ISO C++ 2017 with amendments and GNU extensions' standard
note: use 'c++20' for 'ISO C++ 2020 DIS' standard
note: use 'gnu++20' for 'ISO C++ 2020 DIS with GNU extensions' standard
```

For gcc it is [present in gcc -v --help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252221/2995591).

Comment: `{ clang -std=x -xc++ /dev/null; clang -std=x -xc /dev/null; } 2>&1 | awk -F"'" '$2 != "x"{print "-std="$2}'` looks nice :p . and mixing my other answer `gcc -v --help 2>&1 | grep -o -- '-std=[a-zA-Z+0-9]\+' | sort -u` will also work

Answer (score 2):

Stupid method, but works:

```
strings "$(which gcc)" | grep -o -- '-std=[^] ),.]\+' | sort -u
```

or with man page:

```
man gcc | grep -o -- '-std=[^] ),.]\+' | sort -u
```

Sadly `clang` doesn't work with that, as it seems parsing is done in the shared library. I ended up with:

```
 which clang | xargs ldd | grep libclang-cpp | awk '{print $3}' | xargs strings | grep -o -- '-std=[^] ),.`'\'']\+' | sort -u
```

but it's not all option. `man` works better for clang, but requires more parsing:

```
 man clang | sed -n '/^ *-std=/,/^ *-/{ s/^                 \([^ ]\)/-std=\1/p; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux with [`binutils`](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) installed, you may extract relevant [`strings`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.36/binutils/strings.html), e.g.

```
strings /usr/bin/g++ | grep -e -std=
```

which gives on my computer

```
  -std=<standard>          Assume that the input sources are for <standard>.
--std=
-fobjc-std=objc1
-std=c++03
-std=c++0x
-std=c++11
-std=c++14
-std=c++17
-std=c++1y
-std=c++1z
-std=c++2a
-std=c++98
-std=c11
-std=c17
-std=c18
-std=c1x
-std=c2x
-std=c89
-std=c90
-std=c99
-std=c9x
...
```

and many more.

Answer (score -2):

Some versions of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) accept the `--help` option, the `-dumpversion` option the `--target-help`

So try first running `g++ --help` and `g++ -dumpversion` and `g++ --target-help` commands on your computer, then try `g++ -v --help`. On my [Debian](https://debian.org/) desktop I get useful information from them.

Some versions of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org) accept the `--help` option and the `--version` option.

Both GCC and Clang are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) and have their website giving their latest releases.

#### Maybe you should consider using [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) in your software project?

Another approach is to download the source code of a recent GCC or Clang compiler and compile them on your computer. If on Linux, read [Linux from scratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

It seems that recent C++ standards (see [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better) define preprocessor symbols like `__cplusplus`. See [feature_test_macros(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) and [standards(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html) for Linux.

> How can I get g++ or clang to spew out which versions are available?

I guess you cannot do that reliably and automatically (e.g. with a ten years old laptop found in some attic). Think about [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) tricks. But I would try first running `g++ --version` and `clang --version` and later look on some website.

At last, some obscure features of C++ are not well supported, even in recent GCC. You could ask on the [`gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org` mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html).

However, GCC is [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You are allowed to download its source code, contribute to it and improve it.

Notice that GCC is released (under [GPLv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License)) without warranty and has [bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#known).... You cannot be sure that it compiles your C++ code as you believe it should.

Did you consider having in your C++ code something like

```
#if __cplusplus < 201412L
#error expecting C++17 standard
#endif
```